# Tie Entity Framework calls to a common parameter such as UserId

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

We're creating an application with Entity Framework that deals with data specific to a single user.  The database supports unlimited users so we do need to filter by a UserId.  The SQL Server backend has a common column for all tables (INT UserId).  With every query to the database we have to pass and evaluate a UserId param such as in LINQ, etc.  Is there a good way that we can remove this code so that all queries automatically pass a UserId set at some higher level?  For example, if I want to GetFoo() from the database for a UserId I can have the application call context.GetFoo() and not have to pass the UserId as a param?  Maybe when creating the context for example we could pass the UserId at that level?

Comment: Have each user log into a separate database in the connection string.  Structure you database as system tables so multiple databases (users) can access the system tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this library: https://github.com/jcachat/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters

Just implement an interface w/ a userId on all entities you need to filter by user Id.

```
public interface IUserEntity
{
  int UserId {get; set;}
}
```

Pass in the userId to your DbContext, then in OnModelCreating:

```
modelBuilder.Filter("UserId", (IUserEntity u) => u.UserId, _userId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

in your DbContext, you can define a static property like this

```
public static int UserId;
```

and then you define the following interface

```
public interface IUser
{
   int UserId {get; set;}
}
```

then you will decorate all the entities that have `UserId` by the above `IUser` interface

and inside your `DbContext` you can write the following:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereUser<T>(this DbSet<T> query, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : class,IUser
{
    return query.Where(predicate).Where(t => t.UserId == UserId); 
}
```

you can use the above code as follows

```
using(var db = new YourDbContext())
{
    var details = db.YourDbSet.WhereUser(t=>t.IsActive); 
}
```

hope this will help you

Comment: as mentioned in the question, he can define the UserId in higher level, so you can provide solution without passing the id as param